# Kubernetes Pod DNS Policy Settings

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I am trying to understand the network configuration concepts of Pod in kubernetes. I may have misunderstood the concept and so looking for some suggestion and help.
I Following is my Pod spec where I have set the dnspolicy=true and dnsPolicy to ClusterFirstWithHostNet

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
```

I can see that my pod and host now have the same IP.

```
**k get pod -o wide**


NAME           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES

nginx          0/1     ContainerCreating   0          13s   172.25.0.31   controlplane   <none>           <none>

**k get node -o wide**

NAME           STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION        INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
controlplane   Ready    control-plane,master   5m30s   v1.23.3+k3s1   172.25.0.31   <none>        Alpine Linux v3.15   5.4.0-1069-gcp   containerd://1.5.9-k3s1
```

So my question is why is that when I check the dns config on host and on pod they give a different results. My understanding is that they both should show the same results ?

```
controlplane ~ ➜  cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 172.25.0.1
options ndots:0
```

From POD

```
controlplane ~ ➜  k exec -it nginx -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.43.0.10
options ndots:5
```

Answer (score 0):

`My understanding is that they both should show the same results ?`

Because you set `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` which uses coredns (10.43.0.**10**) in the cluster. If you set to `dnsPolicy: Default` the pod will use 172.25.0.**1** same as your host, but you will not be able to resolved services name deployed in the cluster.